# access static variables/functions in a statically linked library from a dynamic dll

Tags: c++, variables, dll, static, subclass

I am trying to use static class variables and functions in a dynamically loaded dll, which are subclasses of the original class. These static members are used in a statically linked class; this class loads the dlls using a factory, and these dlls should have access to the static functions and variables. Here is a short example as a simple demonstration (i.e., don't expect it to compile; the actual classes have over 1000 lines each):

```
//GenericBase.h-------------------------
#include "GenericDll.h"
class GenericBase{
public:
   GenericBase()
   {
      mClassA.addInstance(this);
   }
   static int mNumInstances;
   static void DoSomething();
   static void Foo();
   static void LoadDlls();
   set<GenericDll*> mPlugins;
};
//--------------------------------------

//GenericDll.h--------------------------
class GenericDll : public GenericBase
{
    void Function();
};
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) GenericDll* CreateModule()
{
    GenericDll * module = new GenericDll();
    return module;
}
//--------------------------------------

//GenericBase.cpp-----------------------
void GenericBase::DoSomething()
{
    for (it = mPlugins.begin(); it != mPlugins.end(); it++)
        it->Function();
}
//--------------------------------------

//GenericDll.cpp------------------------
void GenericDll::Function()
{
    mNumInstances++; // mNumInstancesin GenericDll and mNumInstances in
                    // the static linked GenericBase have different
                    // addresses
    cout << &mNumInstances<<endl;

    Foo();          // again, the address Foo() is different in the dll
}
//--------------------------------------

//main.cpp
int main(){
    GenericBase g;
    GenericBase::LoadDlls(); //not shown
    GenericBase::DoSomething();
    cout << &mNumInstances << endl;
}

//Output: these are the addresses of the mNumInstances
>> 00FAC3B0
>> 0F753398
>> 004D3398
```

So, the overall question or goal is: how can I make the address of mNumInstances the same for the statically linked object, and the dynamically loaded dll classes that subclass this object?

Hopefully this is clear enough, and makes sense!

Comment: Basically, you can't. DLLs are not intended to be a means of sharing data.

Comment: Why not provide accessor methods for your static data in your base and make the data members properly private ?
Worst case, just add a "int * getNumInstancesPtr()" to it .. although its horrible practice of non-encapsulation. Depending on what your subclasses want to do with the data, a more appropriate set of functions would be incrementInstanceCount()/decrementInstanceCount() or something ..

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you wanted to do, you would need to make the shared (copied per DLL) static library a DLL itself.

Think of a DLL as more like an EXE.

Also, be very careful with library versions and compiler and linker settings when returning things like set<> (what ever it is) as things like alignment, data type sizes and different library implementations (inc debug to release) can mean runtime errors (crashes if you are lucky).